# Get value from list of objects Firebase Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code:

```
    public void signOn(String id, String password){
        usersReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                boolean valid = false;
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String key = singleSnapshot.getKey();
                    if (key.equals(id)) {
                        singleSnapshot.getValue()//THIS LINE THIS LINE
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(WelcomePage.this, MainActivity.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("key", key);
                        WelcomePage.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
```

When I call `singleSnapshot.getValue()`, I get `{password=passwordExample, username=usernameExample}` as those are the keys and their values in my Realtime Database. How can I access the password value and the username value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it as `HashMap` and extract value from it, like this.

```
Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) singleSnapshot.getValue();
String username = (String) map.get("username"); // You should pass exact key names here.
String password = (String) map.get("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

The [DataSnapshot#getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()) returns an object of type [Object](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/Object.html). It's true you can cast it to a Map<String, Object>, as GowthamKK mentioned in his answer but there is by far a simpler solution that would get the value according to the corresponding type. So in code, it would be as simple as:

```
String password = singleSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
```

As you can see I have used now, [`<T> getValue(@NonNull Class<T> valueType`)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) which:

> This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot into a class of your choosing.

Comment: Hey there. Have you also tried my solution above?